# How to get objects from one model to other using ForeignKey in Django

Tags: django, django-models, django-views

I want to link models with there ids, I am having trouble in getting objects of foreignkey linked with id and creating queryset, I am new to Django I have searched alot about my problem but not getting answer.

models.py :

```
    class Patient(models.Model): 
        name = models.CharField(max_length=200);
        phone = models.CharField(max_length=20);
        address = models.TextField();
        Patient_id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True);
        Gender= models.CharField(choices=GENDER,max_length=10)
        consultant = models.CharField(choices=CONSULTANT,max_length=20)
        def __str__(self):
            return self.name 

    class Ipd(models.Model):   
        reason_admission = models.CharField(max_length=200, blank=False)
        presenting_complaints = models.CharField(max_length=200,)
        ipd_id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
        rooms = models.ForeignKey(Rooms,on_delete=models.CASCADE, 
    blank=False)
        date_of_admission = models.DateField(("Date"), 
    default=datetime.date.today)  
        patient = 
    models.ForeignKey(Patient,on_delete=models.CASCADE,blank=False)
        def __str__(self):
        return self.patient.name
```

forms.py :

```
    class PatientForm(forms.ModelForm):
        class Meta:
            model = Patient
            fields = ['name', 'phone', 'address', 'Patient_id', 'consultant', 
    'Gender']

    class IpdForm(ModelForm):  
        class Meta:
            model = Ipd

            fields = ['patient','reason_admission','presenting_complaints', 
        'rooms','date_of_admission']
```

views.py:

```
     @login_required
     def ipd (request,patient_id):
         p = Patient.objects.get(pk=patient_id)

         if request.method=="POST":
             formtwo = IpdForm(request.POST,instance=p)
             if  formtwo.is_valid() :
                 formtwo.user_id = request.user.id
                 if formtwo.save():
                     return HttpResponseRedirect('ipd_list.html', 
     messages.success(request, 'Patient is successfully updated.', 'alert- 
     success'))

                 else:
                     return render('ipd_list.html', messages.error(request, 
     'Data is not saved', 'alert-danger'))
             else:
                 return HttpResponse(formtwo.errors) 
         else:
             formtwo = IpdForm()
             return render(request, 'newipd.html', {'p':p ,'form2':formtwo})
```

html :

```
    <div class="card-panel">

    <span class="blue-text text-darken-2">Name : {{p.name}}</span> <br> <span 
    class="blue-text text-darken-2">Phone : {{ p.phone  }}</span><br>
    </div>
```

I am having problem with queryset that allows me to use object of one model to another

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your question isn't very clear but if you want to get an Ipd queryset based on Patient id you would do :

```
qs = Ipd.objects.get(patient=patient_id)
```

If you want a list of Ipd's for a Patient you would do:

```
qs = Patient.idp_set.all()
```

In an html template to get all Ipds for a patient, you would use

```
{{ object.ipd_set.all }} .
```

You need to pass the patient as object.

If you want to loop through this you would need to use:

```
{% for ipd in object.ipd_set.all %}
    do stuff
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: thank you sir! one more question : Can you please tell me what to do in html ?

Comment: thank you Sir ! but i am asking for first queryset! shall i use for loop for that ?

Comment: also i am having "Ipd matching query does not exist." error with that qs

Comment: I've shown how to do a for loop.  You need to actually show some code for be to debug it for you

Answer (score 0):

```
def listing(request):
    queryset_li = Listing.objects.order_by('-list_date')
    context = {
       'listings': queryset_li,
    }
    return render(request, 'listings/listings.html', context)
```